# Call do_action() within WordPress cronjob

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've programmed a cronjob in WordPress which get's executed every 5 minutes. In the function of the cronjob im trying to perform a `do_action`:

```
error_log('Send Email');
do_action( 'trigger_new_subscription_notification_email', $dv_id, $new_order->id );
```

My problem is now that I can see the error_log in the debug.log of WordPress but there is no email sent. When I trigger the cronjob manually like in a `cronmanager`, I receive the email.

I've also disabled `wp_cron` and implemented a real cron call via a linux script.

So is it not possible to do a `do_action` within WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this before the do_action:

```
WC()->mailer();
```

When you do this, it will work!